# Question is marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion

I was on SO just looking around for some fun questions i could help people with and then i marked one as a duplicate but the user is still asking question about the same topic in the comment section of the question.

I pointed out that there is a link in the question that he could check out because the content of the question could help him.

But he is still asking questions in the comments, what should i do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing. You did what you had to do. Mark it as a duplicate. The comments of the OP are not *officialy* doing anything wrong. He's still asking about the topic because it hasn't been officialy closed as a duplicate yet. You also pointed out that there is a link in the question that he could check out, so thats good. So basically **In these cases, mark it as a duplicate and maybe leave a comment.**